# Simple, Excel, =LOOKUP(xxxxx), not returning the correct value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

OK this is infuriating as I know this should work...

I have certain traits in column A.  Each trait has a corresponding value in column B and a numeric indicator of that value in column C.  Like this:

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
| Trait1| Value |Numeric|
| Trait2| Value |Numeric|
| Trait3| Value |Numeric|
```

The values available in column B are:  Amazing, Good, Average, Marginal, Terrible

What I am looking for is a 2 to -2 range to be applied to column C.

What I used...and has worked for me in similar situations before is this:

```
=LOOKUP(C1,{"Amazing","Good","Average","Marginal","Terrible"},{2,1,0,-1,-2})
```

When I drop in Amazing, Average, Marginal and Terrible it works just fine and returns the proper number...for some reason Good is returning 0 instead of 1.

I have the B values utilizing validation from a list so there are no spelling or spacing errors.  Thoughts?

Comment: That's not the only thing that isn't working. Try changing values around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup has been deprecated for a reason.  Sources[1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986) and [2](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lookup-function-HP010342671.aspx):

> The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending order. For
>   example, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 or A-Z or FALSE, TRUE. If you do not do so,
>   LOOKUP may not give the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text
>   are equivalent.

Comment: I have not noticed any indication that the lookup function has been deprecated, and do not see any in the links that you provided. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: If it's deprecated, is there a recommended replacement?

Comment: @MEMark yes, vlookup, hlookup, index(match)

Answer (score 1):

The values being looked up in the `lookup` function (the lookup vector) have to be in ascending order. Then make the Result Vector match. I think you'll find that the following works as expected:

```
=LOOKUP(B1,{"Amazing","Average","Good","Marginal","Terrible";2,0,1,-1,-2})
```

You might want to switch to a `vlookup` or `hlookup` and keep your list in a seperate sheet. Supplying "False" as the last parameter to either of those will allow you to lookup across an unsorted list.

Edited to add: Also I changed your `c1` to `b1` to fit your example.